# Where are the ties at the Gervason's Grocery store?

Tags: achievements, octodad-dadliest-catch

I've turned the whole place upside-down and inside-out, and I still can't find a single lousy tie anywhere in the grocery store.

Where in the world are all the ties?  And why can't I find a single one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the game has been out for awhile, here's where to find all three of these ties.

**Meat Tie**

> Just look underneath the meat cubes behind the deli counter.  The tie is right there.

**Chicken Tie**

> You'll want to climb up onto the Deli counter where the scale is, then climb up onto the dairy display and over to the steel pipes. Carefully balance yourself on those pipes, and make a big step over to the vents to your right.  The Chicken Tie is waiting for you there.

**Banana Tie**

> This one's hiding in plain sight.  You have to break the banana container in the fresh produce section and fish around for it in the wreckage.  It's yellow, so it'll blend in a bit.